# Private school forcing a child to get a specific hairstyle in India

Tags: human-rights, child-abuse, indian-penal-code

If a private school is a forcing a child to get a specific hairstyle, can it be considered as child rights violation in India?

**Update:** The school authorities beat the child and humiliate him in front of the class. His parents are called and he's suspended for a day.

Comment: Does this help: https://www.childlineindia.org.in/pdf/Law-Manual.pdf ?

Answer (score 2):

How is the school forcing the child?

If it's part of the uniform code then that is a condition of the contract between the school and the child's parents; a contract they freely entered into. If the parent's want the child to attend then they can force the child to have the haircut; or withdraw them from the school.

The parent's have every right to dictate how the child gets their hair cut.

Comment: The child is beaten and his head is shaved.

Comment: He is also humiliated in front of the whole class.

Comment: This isn't really a question about a haircut. It is about an assault on a child.

Comment: @uz4ir you may want to edit your question so it includes these very pertinent facts.

Comment: @phoog I would suggest that a different question be asked.